# xlsxwriter `write_row` API with list of formats as parameter?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, spreadsheet, xlsxwriter

So in the docs it is mentioned that `xlsx.worksheet.write_row` is basically a loop over multiple `xlsx.worksheet.write`. I wonder if it is possible to pass multiple formats as an array of formats that is specific for each cell? Something along the line of

```
formats = [
xlsx.workbook.add_format({'italic': True}),
xlsx.workbook.add_format({'bold': True}),
xlsx.workbook.add_format({'align': 'right'}),
]

xlsx.worksheet.write_row(0,0,[1,2, "right aligned text"], formats)
```

It does not seem to be possible by reading the API signature but I just wonder if there is a clever way to do it without calling multiple `write` call each with specific format.

I really appreciate any support.

Comment: No, the parameter for cell format is just that and not a list of formats. You'd be better to use zip to loop both your Data and Cell format lists and just use worksheet.write to write each cell data with its format across the row.